# ACF Repeater and Sort

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

In frontend page outputed ACF Repeater content and I need add dropdown in page frontend with name and date, for sorting for ACF Repeater content.

Comment: i think..get the repeater field content as an array and use jquey-sort will help

Comment: can you show example?